# Calendar getTimeInMillis() returns wrong day

Tags: android, date, calendar

i have a problem with the calendar getTimeInMillis() function which returning invalid day 
first i'm using simple date formatter to format my string date "05/05/2016"

```
SimpleDateFormat mDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

then i put the result parsed date in to the calendar object

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
mCalendar.setTime(mDateFormatter.parse("05/05/2016"));
```

and the function getTime() is returning Thu May 05 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2016
and the function getTimeInMillis() is returning 1462395600000 which equals 
Wed May 04 2016 so there is a difference of one day between the output of the two functions so what isthe problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    mCalendar.setTime(mDateFormatter.parse("05/05/2016"));

    System.out.println("getTime: " + mCalendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("millis : " + mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

    Date date = new Date(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("Date from millis: " + date);
```

And got this output:

```
getTime: Thu May 05 00:00:00 GMT 2016
millis : 1462406400000
Date from millis: Thu May 05 00:00:00 GMT 2016
```

So I'm not seeing the problem you describe.  I used http://ideone.com/  Am I missing something?  Did you do anything to the `Calendar` between `getTime()` and `getTimeInMillis()`?

Comment: hi @nasch i'm sure nothing in the middle :)

Comment: I don't know how to explain it then unless something is operating differently on Android.  That would be strange but I haven't tried it there.  Does your code work correctly on a non-android java platform?